# What is the highest redshift a galaxy with a known stellar mass can be observed?

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, stellar-evolution, stellar-astrophysics, dwarf-galaxy

As part of my research, I would need the following information which it seems I cannot find it in literature. I would like to know what are the highest redshifts at which $10^{7}$, $10^{8}$, and $10^{9}$ $[Solar Unit]$ galaxies can be observed let's say by current HST?

Comment: But you can't see mass, only luminosity, so some sort of assumption is required.

Comment: I mean inferred stellar mass. I just need to reference these saying our best ability to see such stellar masses at the highest redshift. An empirical and generic formula would give me a very crude estimate.

Comment: Much depends on whether you are excluding/including quasar-like activity. The M/L ratio can vary enormously. e.g. Accretion onto a billion solar mass black hole can be seen right back to redshifts $>10$.